# can gitlab replace github for jenkins plugin?

Tags: github, jenkins, gitlab, github-api

We currently use jenkins and github, I want to switch to gitlab, will the jenkins plugins who use github still work with gitlab ?

(GitHub Organization Folder, GitHub pull request builder plugin...)

also, same question for gitolite

Comment: You should strongly consider using the build in Gitlab-CI. It's a great replacement for Jenkins and tightly integrates into gitlab.

Comment: I try to developp a jenkins to github plugin, I need to simulate a github